# Проверка на наличия текста в ячейке БД

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья привет!

Есть колонка "IP" в таблице БД!
Так вот в нее записываются IP всех, кто выполнил определенное действие, через пробел!

Выглядит так примерено: "159.224.34.136 159.224.34.155 153.224.34.156 139.224.34.156"

Подскажите, как проверить наличие IP из этого перечня посредством PHP?

Для примера:
Если при выполнении действие IP 153.224.34.156 есть в ячейке, то выводим текст - такой IP есть, если нет, то нет!

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Первое правило нормализации базы данных: никогда не пихать много значений в одно поле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Текущий IP пользователя
$findip = '159.224.34.136'; 
// Строка всех ip из базы
$data = '159.224.34.136 159.224.34.155 153.224.34.156 139.224.34.156'; 
 // Получаем из строки массив
$darray = explode(" ",$data);
// Проверяем нахождения ip в массиве
if (in_array($findip,$darray)) { 
   echo 'Нашел IP:'.$findip.' в базе';
} else {
   echo 'IP:'.$findip.' отсутствует в базе';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По средствам - значит доступно с материальной точки зрения. Посредством - значит выполнить чем-либо.

Почитайте про выполнение запросов к БД в php. Запрос будет типа `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip=$ip_var`

`$ip_var` - это переменная `php`, в которую вы можете записать адрес, который надо найти в таблице.

Comment: @Get, там конкатенированный через пробел список ipшников. like там будет, а то и три.

Answer (score 0):

```
where viewers like '%'.$ip.'%'
```

Вот эти проценты в запросе вам дадут запись, которая содержит искомый ip.

Comment: не так просто %8.8.8.8% найдет также 118.8.8.8, а %1.1.1.1% найдет еще больше разных комбинаций. Был уже похожий вопрос, в php с таким ужасом лучше работать...

Comment: ну так можно к строке добавить пробелов по сторонам чтобы такого не было . нет разве?

Comment: @Михаил Колев, дело тут не в том, что найти какую-то подстроку в какой-то строке. Вы правы, можно. Дело в неправильной структуре данных.

Comment: ну так базы изначально не проектируют надо делать отдельную табличку в ней айпишники в ячейкас с пренадлежностью к определенной записи

Comment: И вообще айпи адреса (особенно если по ним идет поиск) лучше всего хранить в целочисленном виде, как это делается во всех геокодерах, где айпи диапазоны указаны целыми числами, например, для адреса 77.88.21.8 :
77 * 256^3 + 88 * 256^2 + 21 * 256^1 + 8 * 256^О = 1297618184